# If Statement When Filling Depedent Drop Down Menu Using PhP Ajax SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a functional code that will query a MySQL database and fill a multiple dependent drop down menus. It is roughly based on https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

What I want to be able to do, instead of just passing say "Car Name", I want an if statement, where if "Engine Size" exist for that particular entry, then pass "Car Name" + "Engine Size" so that the menu would be filled with an entry like Ford Escort (2.8L) and if not then just pass the "Car Name" so the menu entry would just be Ford Escort.

The example below will do the full output, Ford Escort (2.8L) but I want to stick an if statement in there, if the engine size doesn't exist for that entry just put Ford Escort, rather than Ford Escort ().

Appreciate any help you can provide.

It should be how to edit this line but I am not experienced enough.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['car_id'].'">'.$row['car_name'].' ('.$row['engine_size'].')'.'</option>';
```

Here is a larger snippet of the code:

```
//Get all material name data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_id = ".$_POST['car_id']);

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//Display material names list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Car Name</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['car_id'].'">'.$row['car_name'].' ('.$row['engine_size'].')'.'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">No car available</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isset() and empty() to check if the value is set and if the content is empty

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 

        // if statment   
    if (isset($row['engine_size']) && !empty($row['engine_size'])) {    
        echo '<option value="'.$row['car_id'].'">'.$row['car_name'].' ('.$row['engine_size'].')'.'</option>';
        // engine size
    } else {
        // no engine size
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.